# Does Clang assembler support 's' suffix for ARM ADD mnemonic

Tags: assembly, arm, clang

Accordingly to [ARM Developer Suite Assembler Guide](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0068/b/ARM-Instruction-Reference/ARM-general-data-processing-instructions/ADD--SUB--RSB--ADC--SBC--and-RSC#:%7E:text=The%20ADD%20instruction%20adds%20the,range%20of%20options%20for%20Operand2%20.) ADD mnemonic has the following syntax

> op{cond}{S} Rd, Rn, Operand2

But it seems Clang has own opinion about ADD capability to update the flag register:

```
alex@alex-VirtualBox:~/jdk17u-dev$ /usr/lib/llvm-13/bin/clang -c -x assembler-with-cpp --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf -marm ./src/hotspot/os_cpu/linux_arm/linux_arm_32.S
./src/hotspot/os_cpu/linux_arm/linux_arm_32.S:97:9: error: instruction 'addlt' can not set flags, but 's' suffix specified
        addlts r2, #32
        ^
./src/hotspot/os_cpu/linux_arm/linux_arm_32.S:145:9: error: instruction 'addlt' can not set flags, but 's' suffix specified
        addlts r2, #32
        ^
./src/hotspot/os_cpu/linux_arm/linux_arm_32.S:178:9: error: instruction 'addlt' can not set flags, but 's' suffix specified
        addlts r2, #32
        ^
./src/hotspot/os_cpu/linux_arm/linux_arm_32.S:230:9: error: instruction 'addlt' can not set flags, but 's' suffix specified
        addlts r2, #32
        ^
./src/hotspot/os_cpu/linux_arm/linux_arm_32.S:335:9: error: instruction 'addlt' can not set flags, but 's' suffix specified
        addlts r2, #32
        ^
./src/hotspot/os_cpu/linux_arm/linux_arm_32.S:400:9: error: instruction 'addlt' can not set flags, but 's' suffix specified
        addlts r2, #16
        ^
./src/hotspot/os_cpu/linux_arm/linux_arm_32.S:463:9: error: instruction 'addlt' can not set flags, but 's' suffix specified
        addlts r2, #32
        ^
./src/hotspot/os_cpu/linux_arm/linux_arm_32.S:496:9: error: instruction 'addlt' can not set flags, but 's' suffix specified
        addlts r2, #32
        ^
```

GCC deals well with it.  Any ideas, maybe a workaround?

Comment: The problem solved by forcing Clang to use GCC assembler with -no-integrated-as.

Comment: IIRC, some assemblers want the predicate embedded like this, others want `addslt`.  Or maybe I'm mixing that up with `ldrblt` vs. `ldrltb` conditional byte-loads.  What does `llvm-objdump -d` say when disassembling machine code assembled with GAS?  If syntax exists to represent this in a way that LLVM's assembler likes, hopefully LLVM's disassembler will use it.

Comment: Please show your source code.  Are you programming in thumb mode or in ARM mode?

Comment: @fuz It's not really mine 

[GitHub](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17u-dev/blob/03eb709ea93e3bf0975f2686523e5d590b6a14f8/src/hotspot/os_cpu/linux_arm/linux_arm_32.S#L97). 

The command line contains -marm thus it seems to be ARM mode

Comment: @AlexeyPavlyutkin Okay, this is an issue of old vs. new ARM syntax.  Clang's own assembler  only  supports the new one.

Comment: assembly language is specific to the assembler not the target (ARM).   in particular one of the variations across assembly languages for arm is as mentioned addslt vs addlts.    Although the disassembler and assembly language for the same tool can/has varied, I often (at least for binutils where this is easy) will generate the machine code then see how the disassembler disassembles it to have a chance at what the assembler might want.......or just read the docs for the assembler, sadly most assemblers do not do a good job with their assembly language documentation.

Comment: @PeterCordes you're right, I faced with ldrh/srth as well, but it's also eliminated by -no-integrated-as, and moreover this way looks preferable to me because it allows to support both GCC/Clang builds without changes to source code, only to build scripts.